# python regular expression get all the text after a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have this string:

```
Email: promo@elysianrealestate.com
```

I want to get the email address:

#### I tried this

```
Email:.*
```

but I got the whole string, not just the email

help please

#### i am using scrapy with python

Comment: Does my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string always finish with the email, you use:

```
r'Email:\s*(.*)'
```

I got the idea from [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.7/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) but I can't test it as I don't have a scrapy shell availabl at the moment.

Comment: I can't use `search` nor `group` because I am using `scrapy`. I must use a single regular expression statement. not functions

Answer (score 2):

This should capture your emails, it ensures that you only capture correctly formed emails:

```
Email:\s+(\b[A-Za-z0-9(._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)
```

Here's how I tested it:

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = """
I have this string:

Email: promo@elysianrealestate.com foo bar baz

I want to get the email address:"""
>>> re.findall(r"""
                Email:\s+
                  (\b                   # edge of first part
                   [A-Za-z0-9(._%+-]+   # name, can be dotted
                   @                    # @
                   [A-Za-z0-9.-]+       # domain, e.g. something.something
                   \.                   # .
                   [A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)     # any lettered end, 2 to 4 letters long
                """, txt, re.VERBOSE)
['promo@elysianrealestate.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a group to mark the text that you want captured. For this, try wrapping the pattern in parenthesis:

```py
r'Email:\s+(.+)'
```

Comment: as suggested below, you may want to use a more restrictive expression for the email, though I don't think is necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the ":" will always separate the "Email" from the actual email address, why not try ( for s = "Email: promo@elysianrealestate.com"):

```
emailAddr = s.split(":")[1].strip()
```

If you need to worry about text after the ".com", just try another split on a " " character and then take the first (0th) element of the list.

```
emailAddr = emailAddr.split(" ")[0]
```